# PHP session_start(); isn't working when is initiated at the top of page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm encountering a very new and strange issue.

Usually `session_start();` is initiated at the top of every page but in my case it's only serving the purpose when it is placed below a included database connection file, something like,

```
<?php
include 'connection.php'; 
session_start(); 
?>
```

`session_start();` doesn't work when it is put reversely like,

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';     
?>
```

Basically the values were initiated and stored in session variables in another file and these should be printed on the page where I'm encountering this strange problem.

What could be the possible reason behind such strange behavior of this function?

Comment: Do you use a custom session handler which requires database access? Or does your 'connection.php' set other session configurations, like the cookie name?

Comment: done any debugging? like turning on display_errors/error_reporting?

Comment: show us connection.php and we might be able to help

Comment: Does `connection.php` include some session-handling functions in it? Are you getting file or DB access errors when `session_start()` is called first?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes, I'm using a `session handler` which requires database access.

Comment: ... looks like that's it then. (At least from what *we* can see.)

Comment: So, that would be correct behavior then. First a database connection, then a `session_start()`. Shouldn't be any problem to keep it in that order.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you encountering error messages?

Comment: @Hugo Delsing, I'm primarily using the handler   http://phpsecurity.org/code/ch08-2 except little change in these lines `$db_connect = mysql_pconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
 if ($_sess_db = mysql_pconnect($db_host, $db_connect)){`

Comment: @Daryl Gill, I only can't print the `session values` when `session_start();` is put at the top of the page but I see no error message in the error log. It's really strange.

Comment: i'm sorry but you make no sense at all. Stop explaining what you think is the problem. Just tell us what you want to do and what is actually happening. Because session_start does work on the first line. It cant fail on the first line. So something completely else is going wrong.  Update the questiin with source and errors or nobody can help.

Comment: Do you also have `session_start();` inside `connection.php`? In order to track any errors, make sure you add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`at the top of your script

Comment: @Pedro Lobito yes, i do have `session_start();` inside connection.php I get no error though error_log in on.

Comment: @ Hugo Delsing, connection.php  has `session_start();` inside it but inactive until these are switched by submitting a form.

Comment: @ Hugo Delsing, `Because session_start does work on the first line. You are very very right.`

Comment: Have you even assigned anything to the session?

Comment: @ Daryl Gill of course. The session values were stored in session variables.

Answer (score 0):

If the included file is a session handler, session should be started below the session handler. In the following code `connection.php` is handling session and creating connection to the database. Therefore, the following code shall initiate the session correctly.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php'; ///// is a session handler
session_start();          ///// shall serve the purpose.
?>
```

on the other hand session won't be initiated when the codes are put in reverse order like,

```
<?php
session_start();          ///// shan't serve the purpose.
include 'connection.php'; ///// is a session handler
?>
```