# Conditional PHP includes aren't serving the purpose

Tags: php, include, conditional-statements

I’m using a conditional statements to switch between two included database connection files like this:

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] == true) { 
 include 'file_a.php'; 
 }else{ 
 include 'file_b.php';
 }
 ?>
```

But it seems that these above equation isn't serving the purpose. Is there any other better approach to totally stop manipulating one file when other one is in use?

Comment: What about this include isn't working?

Comment: That's a poor description of the problem. Why do you think it isn't serving the purpose? What exactly doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: Did you start your session (`session_start()`) before any output is sent to the browser?

Comment: OP's always leave that part out @PetervanderWal 9 times out of 10.

Comment: @ JakeGould, & John Conde I should be able to manipulate the content of `include 'file_a.php';` when session variables are there and not null but in spite of having session variables, the first file can't be connected to database.

Comment: @Peter van der Wal, I've posted a question about `session_start())` issue about half an hour back at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615239/php-session-start-isnt-working-when-is-initiated-at-the-top-of-page?noredirect=1#comment36256334_23615239

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you want to check if `$_SESSION['name'] == true`. This would mean that `$_SESSION['name']` literally has to equal true instead of something like "John" to work. Try:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
  include 'a.php'; 
} else { 
  include 'b.php'
}
```

Comment: and what about `session_start`?)

Comment: Well, he talks about that in another question

Comment: I'm just assuming that ran already.

Comment: Ask the OP lol @Notulysses

Comment: @Bill Criswell I shall try the suggested code. Thanks,